# Is there a way to easily calculate the token given a partition key?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have a UUID partition key that I'd like to calculate its token for. Can this be done easily? I know there's `nodetool getendpoints` and `nodetool getsstables`, but I haven't found a `nodetool` utility for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your partition key is `partition`,

Execute `SELECT token(yourColumn) FROM keyspace.table WHERE yourColumn ='partition' LIMIT 1`

You'll get the token value of your partition key.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! I edited your answer a tiny bit (`LIMIT 1`) to make the output nicer for rows with multiple rows for the same partition key.

Comment: Not sure what the context is, but you can also compute this without a roundtrip to the server. Most drivers with token aware routing have the hash function built in. Python driver, for example: http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/_modules/cassandra/metadata.html#Murmur3Token